# Customer not created when creating new order as admin (Magento 2.3.4)

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.4

When creating a new order in the backend as an admin, you can either select from existing customers or click the "Create New Customer" button. However, we area finding that new customers added in this process are not actually created and are not in the customer grid afterwards.

I've tested with a vanilla installation of Magento 2.3.4 and have not been able to replicate this failure to create a new customer. How might I troubleshoot / fix this?

Comment: Are you on developer mode? Is error reporting and display errors on? Have you checked system.log and exception.log for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting different results from vanilla install and your current repo, let's step through this hopefully we can narrow it down.

Do you see any warnings/notices in sys or exception log pertaining to this process?

Does your non-vanilla installation contain custom code that may be observing/altering related events?

### Debug the logic:

Step through the logic of order creation and update your findings.

Starting points would be these methods in the file `app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php`

1. createOrder()
2. _prepareCustomer()

NOTE: will update answer with feedback from OP

Comment: Thanks so much for stepping up, @LeoFisher! So would you essentially recommend grepping the app/code folder and vendor folders for these methods/classes?

Comment: no, you can go exactly to those files listed and they will have those methods inside.  You will either need to set up a debugger (xdebug) or do some $this->logger to inspect objects and gain insight to why the logic may be failing.    Also do you see anything in the logs around the time that the Order is being generated?

Comment: Thanks @LeoFisher -- would you, for example, log the customer object in the _prepareCustomer() method?

Comment: Yes and check to see if its even entering this condition ```} elseif (!$customer->getId()) {```. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/53ad434d78cd2d357203fb82e5ea059883f403b8/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php#L1807

Comment: Do you see any warnings/notices in sys or exception log pertaining to this process?

Does your non-vanilla installation contain custom code that may be observing/altering related events?

Comment: Hi Leo, I unfortunately haven't been able to debug this completely but I selected your answer for the bounty since I appreciate your attention/time.

Comment: No worries, when you have time ill help out when you come back around to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had an exact same problem after some days of debugging found that there was this patch installed https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/28247 which interrupted creating new customer from admin when creating new order. maybe look through your patches as well (or plugins might also make a problem or observer)